# C# is this a correct usage of ReadOnlySpan<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, memory-management

**Motivation:** I am working on a piece of software that should squeeze as much performance as possible from the machine it works on.

**Hypothesis:** Any `array` in .NET 6 can be converted behind the scenes into a `ReadOnlySpan<T>` or variations of it.

**Question:** Is there any performance benefit if you replace ***all*** function passing parameters from an `array` into a `ReadOnlySpan<T>` ?

**Concrete Example:**

```cs
private float MethodWithArrayOfFloats(float[] arr)
{
    float sum = 0;
    for (var index = 0; index < arr.Length; index++)
    {
        sum += arr[index];
    }
    //What if I would have called here another method passing this array parameter ?
    return sum;
}

private float MethodWithArrayOfSpans(ReadOnlySpan<float> arr)
{
    float sum = 0;
    for (var index = 0; index < arr.Length; index++)
    {
        sum += arr[index];
    }
    //What if I would have called here another method passing this ReadOnlySpan parameter ?
    return sum;
}
```

**Other observations:**

- Prior to asking this question I have profiled both methods using *DotNetBenchmark* and obtained that the `ReadOnlySpan<T>` method is actually faster by about *1ms* on *5_000_000* iterations.
- The JIT ASM code generation on *Sharplab.io* shows that the second method produces more instructions than the first one (and even contains some additional `jmp` instructions)

Nonetheless, this is a mystery for me. Is this a good practice to apply this technique to ***all*** scenarios ? If not why does it seem to be more performant ? What are the hidden implications ?

Comment: `ReadOnlySpan<T>` will be a good benefit because it makes sure there are no additional heap allocations. If you're doing alot of that this will help.

Comment: Is a 1ms gain on 5millions iterations a significant gain for your requirements?

Comment: I'd also suggest that 1ms over 5 million iterations is within any error kind of error bar anyway

Comment: Your current method gains zero benefits from having its `arr` parameter converted to `ReadOnlySpan<T>`. Spans are beneficial where you normally would create copies of parts of an array (e.g. a substring), which is not applicable to your method. Arrays != spans.

Comment: If you want to "squeeze as much performance as possible from the machine it works on" then C# is not your language. It's very optimizable, but you're looking for C++ or something similar with low-level control.

Comment: @silkfire could you elaborate more on this ? Also this method that I came up with it's totally different than the one in my code. This was just for the sake of example

Comment: @DavidG: 1 ms is a million nanoseconds; multi-million clock cycles.  Summing a 5M element array should only take about that long in the first place.  The question is unfortunately missing any details on what the total time is, whether that's a 50% speedup or a 0.0001% speedup, e.g. if they meant 5M iterations of summing an array of some unspecified size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my perspective it should be amost always more performant to use `ReadOnlySpan<T>`. As `ReadOnlySpan<T>` is a ref struct, there are several limitations. And thus the code gets less maintainability. So if what you do is on the hot path of a critical solution use ReadonlySpan, if not use it if it fits and does not complicate your code.

Comment: I've discovered that this is actually true and the code that the JIT is generating is using EBP process register which essentially points to the base of the stack (which might become problematic if overused), but it should be usually faster than ESP which points to a continuous segment in memory. So long story short, `ReadOnlySpan<T>` is faster